# Mysql Performance of rrder by a date field

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following MySql query

```
SELECT DISTINCT cats.name AS cat_name, cats.alias AS cat_alias, content.catid AS cat_id, content.title AS title, content.introtext AS text, content.created AS date, content.publish_up AS date_publish, content.id AS ID, content.alias AS alias, content.hits
    AS hits, content.plugins AS plugins 
FROM t0nbl_k2_items AS content LEFT JOIN t0nbl_k2_categories AS cats ON cats.id = content.catid 
WHERE content.trash = 0 
AND cats.access <=3 
AND content.access <=3 
AND content.published=1 
AND cats.published=1 
AND ( content.publish_up='0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR content.publish_up <='2014-10-31 00:00:00' ) 
AND ( content.publish_down='0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR content.publish_down>= '2014-10-31 00:00:00' ) 
ORDER BY content.created ASC 
LIMIT 0,12;
```

It takes 4 second to get the result.

The explain statement shows the following

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  content     range   item,catid,item_categ,latest    item    10  NULL    11858   Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  cats    eq_ref  PRIMARY,category,published,access,item_categ    PRIMARY     4   site2.content.catid     1   Using where
```

and here are the indexes.

```
INDEXNAME   FIELDNAME
PRIMARY     id
item        published
            publish_up
            publish_down
            trash
            access
catid       catid
created_by  created_by
ordering    ordering
featured    featured
created     created 
language    language
item_categ  access  
            published
            publish_up  
            publish_down
            catid
            created
latest  publish_up  
        publish_down
        created
```

I don't know how to optimize this query to speed it. the #_k2_items has 30.000 items. as you see it is not so big data.
So which indexes i should define to let Mysql use them?

Sorry for my bad english and formating the codes. I am new here to use this editor.

Answer (score 0):

This is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cats.name AS cat_name, cats.alias AS cat_alias, content.catid AS cat_id,
       content.title, content.introtext AS text, content.created AS date,
       content.publish_up AS date_publish, content.id, content.alias, content.hits, content.plugins 
FROM t0nbl_k2_items content JOIN
     t0nbl_k2_categories cats
     ON cats.id = content.catid 
WHERE content.trash = 0 AND cats.access <=3 AND content.access <=3 AND content.published=1 AND
      cats.published=1 AND
      ( content.publish_up='0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR content.publish_up <='2014-10-31 00:00:00' ) AND
      ( content.publish_down='0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR content.publish_down>= '2014-10-31 00:00:00' ) 
ORDER BY content.created ASC 
LIMIT 0,12;
```

One big performance hog is `distinct`.  If you can remove it, remove it.  Next, the `left join` is being undone by the `where` clause.  So, you might as well express it as an `inner join`.

I would suggest indexes on `t0nbl_k2_items(trash, published, access, publish_up, publish_down, catid)` and on `t0nbl_k2_categories(catid, access)`.  With the `distinct` there is no way to eliminate the final `order by`.  Even without the `distinct`, I'm not sure if there is a way.

Comment: thanks for your answer. yes by removing destinct it goes down to 30ms. but i don't know when there will be duplicated rows?

Comment: You can check the individual tables to see if the `join` produces unwanted duplicates.  There is a good chance that it will not produce duplicates unless you have duplicates in one of the tables -- which would be a data quality problem.